# Import csv without double quotes

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I have a database with several columns containing various data, I'm importing and exporting like so

```
$Col1= Import-CSV  C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\dbs.csv | select Col1 
$Col1|%{$(Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($_.GivenName)}
$Col1|  Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation   C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Names.txt
```

When the file exports into the Names.txt each line contains double qoutes like so

```
"Category"
"Employees"
```

Contents of the database

```
Col1 #Col1 is the header or the name of the column
Category
Employees
...
...
```

How can I remove those quotes when I export the data from the `csv` into a `txt` file?

Comment: Please add a sample of the original data from `dbs.csv`.

Comment: I updated the question @vonPryz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Out-File when outputting to a .txt file

```
$Col1|  Out-file C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Names.txt
```

Comment: Thanks that works but now my foreach loop prints what I want to add to it under each row rather than beside it like I had it before with export-csv, should I create a new question for this?